# python requests returns different headers for same url GET request

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-requests

I'm hitting the same website multiple times and every so often `requests` is returning the **full** page (as seen by the `Content-Length`. I've included the header parameters which were different for that particular request.

```
url = "http://www.atpworldtour.com/players/roger-federer/f324/player-activity?year=2016"
while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    print r.headers

# {... , 'Content-Length': '40940', ... , 'Age': '807', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', ...,  'X-ATP-Server': 'web4', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202146 ...', ...}
# {... , 'Content-Length': '40940', ... , 'Age': '807', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', ...,  'X-ATP-Server': 'web4', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202146 ...', ...}

...

# {... , 'Content-Length': '40940', ... , 'Age': '808', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', ...,  'X-ATP-Server': 'web4', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202146 ...', ...}
# {... , 'Content-Length': '41632', ... , 'Age': '817', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Trace': '1B7F99....', ... , 'X-ATP-Server': 'web1', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202055 ...', ...}
# {... , 'Content-Length': '40940', ... , 'Age': '812', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', ...,  'X-ATP-Server': 'web4', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202146 ...', ...}
# {... , 'Content-Length': '40940', ... , 'Age': '814', ... , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', ...,  'X-ATP-Server': 'web4', ... , 'Via': '1.1 sng202146 ...', ...}

...
```

I don't know much about html to know if this is due to some of the page being generated by js on the fly but I would like to force `requests` to return the page of length 41632 every time. I also haven't experimented with the timeout parameter as the requests are all returning correctly (with status code `200`) however with varying lengths.

Comment: Given that the difference is an `X-Trace` header, this is probably just some additional header data used by the operators of `atpworldtour.com` to occasionally trace their network stack for debugging purposes. The page itself is likely not very different.

Comment: Sadly, when I go to scrape the page the content is in fact different (hence how I noticed the issue in the first place). I will try and find a reproducible example of the missing content